# Using header returned from auth_request in nginx logs - $sent_http_* stopped working

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

We are using `ngx_http_auth_request_module` for authentication in our web application.

The auth endpoint returns some headers, one of them is attached to the outgoing request.
The others were used to add metadata to the nginx logs (like who made the request and so on).

The log format is something like this:

```
    log_format  main  '[$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" ; sent_http_x_my_type: $sent_http_x_my_email';
```

Basically `sent_http_x_my_type: $sent_http_x_my_email` would attach the user email as returned from the auth_request endpoint to the access logs. Everything was working (we were running an old version of ingress-nginx which is using nginx version `1.20.1`).

Since upgrading to a newer version of ingress-nginx we are now running nginx version `1.21.6`.

For some reason the $sent_http headers are no longer set automatically. The only way to have them work and appear in logs is by adding this to the location definition

`auth_request_set $authHeader1 $sent_http_x_my_email;`
Its as if you have to access this variable so it resolves.

Here is an example of nginx.conf to reproduce the issue:

```
#pcre_jit on;
worker_processes  auto;

#error_log  logs/access.log notice;
error_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    underscores_in_headers          on;

    log_format  main  '[$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" ; sent_http_x_my_type: $sent_http_x_my_email';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 8888;

        location /auth {
            access_log off;
            add_header x-my-session 'x-my-session-set';
            add_header x-my-email 'test@email.com';
            add_header x-my-type 'internal';

            return 200;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8889;

        location /test {
            access_log off;
            return 200 "valid";
        }
    }

    server {
        location /test {
            auth_request        /auth;
            auth_request_set $authHeader0 $upstream_http_x_my_session;
            #auth_request_set $authHeader1 $sent_http_x_my_email; # <-- The value appears in the log only if this is uncommented.
            proxy_set_header 'x-my-session' $authHeader0;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8889;
            proxy_redirect                          off;
        }

        location = /auth {
            internal;

            access_log off;

            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8888;
            proxy_pass_request_body off;
            proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
            proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea why its working like this? Is there some flag I can turn on to have the $sent_http variable load?

Thanks!